# Lex is unable to access the Lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am getting this error when i try to add a lambda function for fulfillment in lex:

```
Lex is unable to access the Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:843706464800:function:OrgbotFulfillment in the context of intent arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:843706464800:intent:Add:$LATEST. Please check the resource-based policy on the function
```

This error is occurring for only one intent out of the ten intents my bot has, while the same fulfillment function is being used for all of them.Where is the cause and How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you complete the build/publish process after creating that last intent?

Comment: Yes i did build, but not publish. The  error came up at the time of building

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate the issue, but you may want to try deleting your 10th intent from your bot and delete from list of intents as well.  Then recreate it.  If that still doesn't work, I would recommend going to the list of intents from the Main Lex page (not within your bot) and Export one of your working Intents and export the non-working one.  Double-check that the fulfillment codehook uri is the same.  You may even try building your 10th intent as a json object with the appropriate fulfillment uri and importing it here to see if you can overcome this error.  Good luck.

Comment: unable to recreate the error...

Answer (score 2):

The List comes from your lambdas in the same region. 
AWS Lambda needs access permission to Lex.

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name <lambda_name> --statement-id chatbot-fulfillment --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "lex.amazonaws.com"
```